# What is the chance of Skell Overdrive being extended?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-x

In the in-game manual, it is stated that while using Overdrive with a Skell, the duration may be sometimes increased:

> **Extending Skell Overdrive**
>   A Skell's Overdrive mode will be extended randomly.

Unfortunately, that is all that's mentioned. Similarly, the wiki provides no further information.

**So, what is the chance that Overdrive is extended? Is it even a known value?

Additionally, are there any factors that affect this chance? (Skell type, gear, etc.)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The chance for Skell Overdrive to be extended seems to be dependent on the number of times it has already been extended and the number of times [Cockpit Time](http://xenoblade.wikia.com/wiki/Cockpit_Time) has been activated.**

Quoting from [this site](http://www.gameskinny.com/9m36l/xenoblade-chronicles-x-guide-skell-info-and-combat) where I found the information:

> Overdrives gives a higher chance to activate cockpit for each art used and can be extended up to 5 extra times.
>
> - 1st - 100% chance to extend, 30% chance to activate cockpit. Last 15 seconds.
> - 2nd - 100% chance to extend, 20% chance to activate cockpit. Lasts 13 seconds.
> - 3rd - 50% plus 20% for each cockpit activated, 30% chance to activate cockpit. Lasts 13 seconds.
> - 4th - 0% plus 20% for each cockpit activated, 20% chance to activate cockpit. Lasts 13 seconds
> - 5th - 0% plus 20% for each cockpit activated, 30% chance to activate cockpit. Lasts 13 seconds.
> - 6th - 20% chance to activate cockpit.